# Why are there two non-trivial T-invariant subspaces and why the restriction to T is cyclic?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

Given that T is a cyclic operator on real vector space V with generating vector v, and minimal polnyomial $\mu_{T,v}(x) = x^3 - 8$.
I see a theorem in my book stating that every T-invariant subspace of $V = <T,v>$ is cyclic, so I can see why the restriction to T of these T-invariant subspaces is cyclic, but I don't know why these 2 non-trivial T-invariant subspaces exist. Any pointers?
Also, how can we give explicit generators in terms of T and v for these nontrivial T-invariant subspaces? I am having a hard time with this chapter and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal polynomial is reducible: $\mu_T(x) = (x-2)(x^2 + 2x + 4)$. Each divisor of the minimal polynomial gives you a different invariant subspace; for instance, the divisor $x-2$ gives you the invariant subspace $\ker(T-2I)$, which is generated by $(T^2 + 2T + 4I)v$.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!
I tried finding the other invariant subspace, and I got $ker(T^2 + I)$, generated by $(T-2I)v$. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure how you got $\ker(T^2+I)$, it should be $\ker(T^2+2T+4I)$. But at least the generator is right :-)

Comment: Oops, I tried factoring $x^2+2x+4$, which felt wrong, but now I see how to get the correct subspace. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, in general if $V$ is $T$-cyclic generated by $v$, and $\mu_T(x) = f(x)g(x)$, then $\ker f(T) = g(T)V$ is $T$-cyclic and generated by $g(T)v$.